# Ecological interpretation of Lotka-Volterra model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I am studying Lotka-Volterra models, specifically one of prey-predator with intraspecific competition. The equation system is:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}= r_x x(1-x-\alpha y)$$
$$\frac{dt}{dt}= r_y y(\beta x + \gamma y -1)$$
where $x$ correspond to preys and $y$ to predators,
$$r_x,r_y,\alpha,\beta >0$$
and 
$$\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$$

I know $r_x$ is the growth tax for preys, $r_y$ is the death tax for predators and $\alpha$, $\beta$ are their interaction taxes, all of them are real positive numbers.

$\gamma$ is the logistic term for predators, but I don't understand why it can be positive or negative. If $\gamma$ is negative, it means competition between predators, but which ecological interpretation has a positive $\gamma$ value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With negative $\gamma$, this term stands for the reaction 
$$
2Y\to Y,
$$
environmental pressure leads to a reduction in the population.

With $\gamma$ positive, the term stands for the reaction
$$
2Y\to 3Y,
$$
which could for instance mean that any encounter of $2Y$ leads to (in average) an increase in the population

Comment: So if it's positive, does that mean the rate of predators real increase is positive as well? I mean: births + immigration > deaths + emigration.

Comment: In principle yes. $γ<0$ means death by any causes by competition for resources. $γ>0$ as birth term would mean that no monogamous pairing occurs as with a linear birth term, but that any random meeting can lead to procreation. More realistically one would blend both in some way, quadratic for small $y$, tending to linear for large $y$. // If you want to you can also consider this a balance term of those two influences.

Answer (score 1):

$\gamma y$ , according to Wikipedia, is the "loss rate of the predators due to either natural death or emigration."

Hence, a positive $\gamma$ would correspond to high immigration rates of the predator. (High, as in immigration > natural death)

Comment: Does that mean $\gamma$ could correspond to a higher birth rate than death? Or it's just immigration?